# What is the Windows equivalent of the GNU ld flag --whole-archive?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, linker

I have a static library `A` and a dynamic library `B` that links to `A` (on Linux `A/libA.a` and `B/libB.so`, on Windows `A/A.lib` and `B/B.dll`).  On Linux I can cause `B` to contain all the symbols in `A` by using this link line:

```
g++ -shared -o libB.so B_init.o ... -Wl,--whole-archive -L../A -lA -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

How would I do the equivalent on Windows?  (Assume that I have correctly exported the symbols in `A` with the correct `__declspec(dllexport)` decorations.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Visual studio equivalent to GNU ld option --whole-archive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867254/what-is-the-visual-studio-equivalent-to-gnu-ld-option-whole-archive)