# How to force MSVC to link an unused static library (Equivalent of GCCs --whole-archive parameter)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

There is a static library which is used by the main program indirectly. Therefore there is no missing reference and the static library is not linked.

The same problem was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116420/how-to-force-gcc-to-link-an-unused-static-library) for the GCC. And the proposed solution worked for me as well. But now I need to build the program with MSVC. So I suppose that I need the equivalent of GCC's `--whole-archive` parameter?

At the moment the linker call is like that: `link.exe /nologo /out:program.exe staticLib.lib main.obj`

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37635773/990618

Answer (score 0):

I recently met with the same problem while trying to link googletest with library containing the tests and found the following note in their [primer](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer#Important_note_for_Visual_C++_users) :

> When you define your tests, Google Test creates certain static objects
>   to register them. These objects are not referenced from elsewhere but
>   their constructors are still supposed to run. When Visual C++ linker
>   sees that nothing in the library is referenced from other places it
>   throws the library out. You have to reference your library with tests
>   from your main program to keep the linker from discarding it. Here is
>   how to do it. Somewhere in your library code declare a function:
>
> ```
> __declspec(dllexport) int PullInMyLibrary() { return 0; }
> ```
>
> If you put your tests in a static library (not DLL) then `__declspec(dllexport)` is
>   not required. Now, in your main program, write a code that invokes
>   that function:
>
> ```
>       int PullInMyLibrary();
>       static int dummy = PullInMyLibrary();
> ```
>
> This will
>   keep your tests referenced and will make them register themselves at
>   startup.
>
> In addition, if you define your tests in a static library, add
>   `/OPT:NOREF`to your main program linker options.

While this may be no the most beautiful workaround ever this certainly worked for me and I think if there would be the one better they would have mentioned it in their primer instead.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867254/what-is-the-visual-studio-equivalent-to-gnu-ld-option-whole-archive

Comment: This is not a bug, despite the claim on the page to which you link.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis yeah, I've tested it on linux and it looks like it doesn't work without `--whole-archive` either. Guess better solution is to organize program in different way after all.