# ODB C++ - Unknown database schema error

Tags: c++, database, schema, odb, codesynthesis

In my `Visual Studio` solution, I have two different projects of which one is built as a `static library`and the other one as the executable. The `ODB` related code like creating the database and all are in the library. I linked this library to my executable. But when I debug the executable code, I get the error `"unknown database schema"` in the call `create_schema()`.I am using `SQLite` as my database. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you tried to create something in sqlite manually? Maybe your linking to sqlite broke in your executable

Comment: @Superlokkus: No I didnt create anything manually.

Comment: You'd misunderstood me: Please try to create something manually with sqlite, to make sure sqlite is actual working, and to exclude the scenario that ODB did nothing wrong, because you can't use sqlite anyway.

Comment: @Superlokkus: When I add the files generated by the odb compiler with the executable rather than the  library, everything goes fine. So SQLITE is working, rght?

Comment: No, try for example to open a file database with, I'm not sure; `sqlite3_open`

Answer (score 0):

This problem is likely related to the issues described [here](http://www.codesynthesis.com/pipermail/odb-users/2013-May/001286.html) and [here](https://odb-users.codesynthesis.narkive.com/3Ms11hIV/create-schema-error-unknown-database-schema), and which can be briefly summarised as follows: the C/C++ linker will ignore symbols from the static libraries if these symbols are not directly used in the main binary. ODB's implementation can fall into this trap, depending on how exactly you are instantiating the generated code. For GCC/Clang the solution is to use `--whole-archive` and for MSVC, on Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and above,
`/WHOLEARCHIVE`.

For more details see:

- [ld linker question: the --whole-archive option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805555/ld-linker-question-the-whole-archive-option)
- [What is the Microsoft Visual Studio equivalent to GCC ld option --whole-archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867254/what-is-the-microsoft-visual-studio-equivalent-to-gcc-ld-option-whole-archive)