# Visual Studio doesn't link a file into the binary when it finds no definitions in the file is used external

Tags: c++, visual-studio, factory, factory-pattern

I am trying to use factory mode to create some derived class.

Here are the details about it:

---

### Purpose:

There are two classes `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` derived from **BaseClass**. Class `DerivedA` is defined in `derived_class_A.h/cpp` and `DerivedB` in `derived_class_B.h/cpp`.

Also there is a **factory** class `Factory` in `factory.h/cpp` to create `DerivedA` or `DeriveB`.

Our purpose is that, the `Factory` is allow to create `DerivedA` if and only if `derived_class_A.cpp` is compiled, meanwhile we don't want to have any information about `DerivedA` in the `factory.h/cpp`.

So we cannot use `switch case(){...}` to call new `DerivedA()` in the `factory`, nor can we use `MACROS` to distinguish `DerivedA` and `DerivedB`.

---

### Our Implementation

In the Factory class, we have a static method:

```
template<class classname> Factory::RegisterClass<classname>(int key);
```

It uses a `std::map` to map the key keyA to the new `DerivedA()` function, and keyB to new `DerivedB()` function.

Then in the `BaseClass* Factory::CreateClass(int Key)` method, it can
get the creator of `DerivedA/DerivedB` according to the key.

In `derived_class_A.cpp`, we are trying to calling the `RegisterClass` during the library loading. Here is the way we use:

```
class tempClassA { tempA() { Factory::RegisterClass<DerivedA>(keyA); } };
static tempClassA tempA;
```

In this way, if `derived_class_A.cpp` exists, the `RegisterClass` of `DerivedA` will be called when the static variable tempA is initialized.

If `derived_class_A.cpp` is not compiled, then static variable `tempA` doesn't exist and the `RegisterClass` of `DerivedA` **won't be called**. This is the result we expected.

---

### Issues:

This method works perfectly when we build the code as a shared library directly, or as an executable.

However, when we build it to a static library and then linked into a final shared library with other libs, seems that the `derived_class_A.o` is not linked into the **shared library**.

We think it is caused by the fact that no definitions in `derived_class_A.cpp` is referred explicitly in other files. The Factory class call the creator of `DerivedA` implicitly.

Here is an experiment to prove that it is not linked:

1. We declare a function using "`extern`", but doesn't implement it. We call this fake function in `derived_class_A.cpp`, and it doesn't report any linking error either in the static library building or latter building the static lib into the final shared library.
2. If we define a variable "`int A`" in `derived_class_A.cpp` and refer it using "`extern int A`" in `factory.cpp`. (In fact we can't do that in our project since we can't including any information from `derived_class_A.cpp` in `factory.cpp`.) In this case `derived_class_A.o` will be linked as it will report an linking error about the fake function we added in step 1.

---

### Questions

- So can I force a file to be linked in the final library even non of
  its definition is referred external?
- If not, is there any other choice to implement this mechanism? I know on Linux `__attribute__((constructor))` can guarantee the `registerClass` function called when the library is loaded. But I didn't find any similar tools on Windows VS.

---

Thanks a lot for watching this.

---

Comment: Looks suspiciously like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867254/what-is-the-microsoft-visual-studio-equivalent-to-gcc-ld-option-whole-archive

Comment: Hi MSalters, thanks a lot. That's exactly the issue I met with, and using the /WHOLEARCHIVE can solve it completely.